MudBlazor Multiselect Data Binding Issue while Editing or selecting Values
I have a multiselect which is a collection of a class
<MudSelect MultiSelection="true"SelectAll="true" SelectAllText="All"T="Theater" Label="Theatre" @bind-SelectedValues="@_selectedtheatervalue"AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.ArrowDropDown"Variant="Variant.Outlined" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter"  ToStringFunc="@(e => e.TheaterName)">@foreach (var theaters in ddlTheater){<MudSelectItem T="Theater" Value="@theaters">@theaters.TheaterName</MudSelectItem>}</MudSelect>

While editing lick from mudtable, same mudselect is filling up but check boxes are not getting checked:

how to rebind during editing from mudtable? on selection select should show value
